# Insert structure arrays dynamic in C. Exited, segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I have a problem with structure arrays, to insert dynamic values.

Cannot insert values ​​into dynamic arrays, response "Exited, segmentation fault".

Can anyone help me, that's problem.
Thank you
............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Syntax:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FLUSH while (getchar() != '\n') 

typedef struct{
    char *Name;
    int Qty;
} Item;

static void insert(Item* i, char *name, int qty)
{
    i->Name = name;
    i->Qty = qty;
}

int main() {

    int storage = 0, menu;
    printf("Temporary Storage\n");

    //Input storage amount
    bool isInputStorage = true;
    while (isInputStorage) {
        printf("Input Storage amount [1..10]: ");
        scanf("%d", &storage);

        if (storage <= 10 && storage >= 1) {
            isInputStorage = false;
        }
        else {
            printf("\n[!]Please enter numbers [1..10] for Storage amount.\n\n");
        }
        FLUSH;
    }

    Item *dataItems;

    //Input Menu
    bool isInputMenu = true;
    while (isInputMenu) {

        printf("\n\nMenu\n");
        printf("=============\n");
        printf("1. Add items\n");
        printf("4. Exit\n");
        printf("Choose Menu [1..4]: ");
        scanf("%d", &menu);

        if (menu >= 1 && menu <= 4) {

            if (menu == 1) {
                char* name;
                int qty;

                //Insert to arrays storage
                int currentStorageAmount = sizeof(dataItems) / sizeof(dataItems[0]);
                if (currentStorageAmount >= storage) {
                    printf("Storage is Full");
                }
                else {

                    printf("Input name of Item : ");
                    scanf("%s", name);

                    bool isQty = true;
                    while (isQty) {
                        FLUSH;
                        printf("Input qty of Item : ");

                        int correctQty = scanf("%d", &qty);

                        if (correctQty == 1) {
                            isQty = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            printf("\n[!]Please enter number for Qty!\n\n");
                        }

                    }

                    //action to insert
                    insert(&dataItems[currentStorageAmount], name, qty);

                }
            }
            else if (menu == 4) {
                printf("\nThank you for using this application.\n");
                isInputMenu = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("\n[!]Please enter numbers [1..4] for choose Menu.");
        }

        menu = 0;
        FLUSH;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Temporary Storage
Input Storage amount [1..10]: 4

Menu
=============
1. Add items
4. Exit
Choose Menu [1..4]: 1
Input name of Item : test
Input qty of Item : 5
exited, segmentation fault
```

Comment: `dataItems` is not initialized to any memory location and could be located anywhere in memory, allocate the "dynamic array", either using `Item dataItems[storage]` or `Item *dataItems = malloc(sizeof(Item) * storage)` and check `dataItem` before using.

Comment: You can't do `char* name;...scanf("%s", name);` because you haven't created any memory for the name to go - in fact you haven't initialized the pointer to ANYTHING.  It's the same problem that @dvhh mentioned.  Basically you need to initialize ALL your variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking about arrays but there is no one array in your code...

What you really have is the pointer to Item. This means three things:

1. You have not initialized this pointer, and it points to *somewhere*. So the expression `&dataItems[currentStorageAmount]` gives you a random position in memory that leads you to the segmentation fault.
2. The expression `sizeof(dataItems) / sizeof(dataItems[0])` gives you something different from what you expect: size of the pointer divided to size of the structure. In other words it is zero.
3. You need to allocate memory before using the `dataItems`.

Answer (score 0):

I check the code with GDB, the error is at line 65,

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

you have declared a pointer char* name, but you have not allocated its heap memory yet. The correct solution is to change the line,

```
char *name
```

To

```
char* name = malloc(128);
```

Then, the code is running.